# Why is this result not significant?

Tags: anova, statistical-significance

I am reading a research paper about the relationship between service quality and consumer behavior. One hypothesis is: customers experiencing no service problems have the strongest levels of favorable behaviors and the smallest levels of unfavorable behaviors.
ANOVA was operated, results are:

[image]

The author intepreted:

"The pay more intentions of customers experiencing no service problems are not significantly higher than those of customers experiencing service problems that were resolved."

But the significance level for this factor was ,036, less than ,05. It should be significant, right?  (The author used ,05 as standard for other analysis )

Comment: It's clearly explained under the table what was done and why. The 0.05 level was the *overall* type I error rate; the per-test type I error rate was therefore lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the details printed below the table it tells you that they used a Bonferroni correction to yield a critical alpha level of 0.006.